# Windows: Use tree /f to specify only files with specific extension

Tags: windows, tree

I'm working on windows server 2012. With `tree /f` I'm able to show a tree of a folder with al its files in it.
But I only want to show my `.docx` in this tree:
So something like:

```
tree /f | *.docx
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can use `findstr` to filter but you're going to lose context.